# Azure Devops deploying Python Azure Function not working

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops

I Have a YAML pipeline line within Azure DevOps to build and deploy some python to an Azure Function.

The YAML is auto generated from selecting "Python Function App To Linux On Azure". It then asks me to select the subscription and azure function and that is it.

When it deploys to the Azure Function and I try to call it I get back a 500 and if I go to Monitor I see the 500 was a result of it not finding a module. Initially this was oauth2client (I was using the classic editor to configure to job before I changed to YAML) and it is now throwing an error on numpy

> Failure Exception: ImportError: Unable to import required
> dependencies: numpy:

If I deploy from visual studio code it all works fine and as expected

I have utilised the call to

**https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings**

to get the underlining package that it is using, and I downloaded the package that is uploaded via VS Code and via the YAML and they have the same contents.

Not sure what is going wrong with this.

Cheers
Mark

Comment: I'm having this EXACT problem trying to deploy a Python Azure Function, from Enterprise Github, using Azure DevOps. Can't seem to figure out how to get all the packages and dependencies downloaded during the build process. The packages are not committed to Github. Tried using a PowerShell ADO step of `py -m venv .venv`, `. .venv\scripts\activate`, then `pip install -r E:\e\_\2\s\requirements.txt`.

Comment: But the Function App doesn't know what to do with the resulting `.venv/Lib/site-packages` inside the .zip file. Doesn't load them.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 3.7, you are required to install the dependencies in `.python_packages` folder.

`pip install --quiet --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode

Since you are using vscode, you can also inspect the files when you open the Azure Extension and inspect the `Files`

Comment: I need to check but I am sure my package already writes the dependencies to .python_packages

Comment: I looked and confirmed the dependencies are in .python_packages

Comment: Okay, and I assume that ".python_packages" folder is in the root of your directory also. 
On the installation process in the Devops pipeline, do you activate a venv / conda env etc?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. The .python_packages folder is in the root directory. I am just using the default Azure Function App Deploy with Azure DevOps, so i am not explicitly telling it to activate venv or conda but it may be doing that itself, I am unsure.

Comment: @markblue777 were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This resolves the issue. Its azure Devops outdated template that caused the issue for me

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/827

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32938783)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).